# How to pass result of script template as an input parameter to another task in dag in argo workflows

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I created a `WorkflowTemplate` in which I want to pass result of a script template as an input parameter to another task

Here is my `WorkflowTemplate`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: dag-wft
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: message
          default: '["tests/hello", "templates/hello", "manifests/hello"]'
    dag:
      tasks:
        - name: prepare-lst
          template: prepare-list-script
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: message
                value: "{{inputs.parameters.message}}"

        - name: templates
          depends: prepare-lst
          templateRef:
            name: final-dag-wft
            template: whalesay-final
          arguments:
            parameters:
            - name: fnl_message
              value: "{{item}}"
          withParam: "{{tasks.prepare-lst.outputs.parameters.templates_lst}}"

        - name: manifests
          depends: prepare-lst && (templates.Succeeded || templates.Skipped)
          templateRef:
            name: final-dag-wft
            template: whalesay-final
          arguments:
            parameters:
            - name: fnl_message
              value: "{{item}}"
          withParam: "{{tasks.prepare-lst.outputs.parameters.manifests_lst}}"

  - name: prepare-list-script
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: message
    script:
      image: python
      command: [python]
      source: |
        manifests_lst = []
        # templates list preparation
        templates_lst = ['templates/' for template in "{{inputs.parameters.message}}" if 'templates/' in template]
        
        print(templates_lst)

        # manifests list preparation
        for i in "{{inputs.parameters.message}}":
          if 'templates/' not in i:
            manifests_lst.append(i)

        print(manifests_lst)

    outputs:
      parameters:
        - name: templates_lst
        - name: manifests_lst
```

In the above script template I've added print statement of two variables `templates_lst` and `manifests_lst`. I want to pass these two variables result as in input to two other tasks in the dag. The two other tasks are `templates` and `manifests`

The way I am accessing the output values is `"{{tasks.prepare-lst.outputs.parameters.templates_lst}}"` and `"{{tasks.prepare-lst.outputs.parameters.manifests_lst}}"`. It is not working

How we can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Fully define your output parameters**

Your output parameter spec is incomplete. You need to specify *where* the output parameter comes from.

Since you have multiple output parameters, you can't just use standard out (`{{tasks.prepare-lst.outputs.parameters.result}}`). You have to write two files and derive an output parameter from each.

**2. Load the JSON array so it's iterable**

If you iterate over the string representation of the array, you'll just get one character at a time.

**3. Use an environment variable to pass input to Python**

Although it's not strictly necessary, I consider it best practice. If a malicious actor had the ability to set the `message` parameter, they could inject Python into your workflow. Pass the parameter as an environment variable so the string remains a string.

**Changes:**

```
   - name: prepare-list-script
     inputs:
       parameters:
         - name: message
     script:
       image: python
       command: [python]
+      env:
+      - name: MESSAGE
+        value: "{{inputs.parameters.message}}"
       source: |
+        import json
+        import os
+        message = json.loads(os.environ["MESSAGE"])
         manifests_lst = []
         # templates list preparation
-        templates_lst = ['templates/' for template in "{{inputs.parameters.message}}" if 'templates/' in template]
+        templates_lst = ['templates/' for template in message if 'templates/' in template]
         
-        print(templates_lst)
+        with open('/mnt/out/templates_lst.txt', 'w') as outfile:
+          outfile.write(str(json.dumps(templates_lst)))
 
         # manifests list preparation
         for i in "{{inputs.parameters.message}}":
           if 'templates/' not in i:
             manifests_lst.append(i)
 
-        print(manifests_lst)
+        with open('/mnt/out/manifests_lst.txt', 'w') as outfile:
+          outfile.write(str(json.dumps(manifests_lst)))
+      volumeMounts:
+      - name: out
+        mountPath: /mnt/out
+    volumes:
+    - name: out
+      emptyDir: { }
 
     outputs:
       parameters:
         - name: templates_lst
+          valueFrom:
+            path: /mnt/out/templates_lst.txt
         - name: manifests_lst
+          valueFrom:
+            path: /mnt/out/manifests_lst.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same way initially but it is giving this error `Failed: invalid spec: templates.whalesay-wf.tasks.templates-wf templates.whalesay.tasks.prepare-lst templates.prepare-list-script.outputs.parameters.templates_lst: k8sapi executor does not support outputs from base image layer. Use an emptyDir: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/empty-dir/`.

Also I tried adding `VolumeMounts` and `volumes` but no luck

Comment: @Biru I've updated the example with the changes recommended in the paged linked from the error message.

Comment: @Biru if it's still not working after checking against the example, can you post a new question with the failing WorkflowTemplate?

Comment: It worked, but passing these outputs as an input parameters to other tasks is not correct. currently am passing the value is `withParam: "{{tasks.prepare-lst.outputs.parameters.templates_lst}}"` but it is giving the error like `Failed: invalid spec: templates.whalesay-wf.tasks.templates-wf v1alpha1.WorkflowTemplate.Spec: v1alpha1.WorkflowTemplateSpec.WorkflowSpec: Templates: []v1alpha1.Template: v1alpha1.Template.DAG: v1alpha1.DAGTemplate.Tasks: []v1alpha1.DAGTask: v1alpha1.DAGTask.WithParam: ReadString: expects " or n, but found [, error found in #10 byte..`

Comment: @Biru can you post a link to the full spec that you're running? Looks like the YAML doesn't match the Workflow spec, but without the full YAML I'm unable to see what's wrong.

Comment: I will be posting a new question with the new error am facing

Comment: I fixed it. The issue is list is not storing properly in file. I've used `json.dumps` which replaces single quotes of a string in list to double quotes and this works for `withParam`

@Michael Crenshaw - I updated your answer and accepting it as a working resolution.

Comment: @Biru oh geez sorry I shoulda remembered that. Glad you found it!